# R update function, how to drop all the variables that are related to a pre-specified variable

Tags: r, statistics, formula

I have a R formula object:

```
 formula1 <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2
```

I want to update this formula object by dropping all x1-related variables. That is x1 AND x1:x2.

If I use an update function,

```
 update(formula1,.~.-x1)
```

I get:

```
 y ~ x2 + x3 + x1:x2
```

This is not what I want. In practice, I do not know how many interaction effects of x1 are defined in the formula1 object.

Is there simple way to get

```
 y ~ x2 + x3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function to remove a term including all interactions in which the term is present:

```
remove_terms <- function(form, term) {
  fterms <- terms(form)
  fac <- attr(fterms, "factors")
  idx <- which(as.logical(fac[term, ]))
  new_fterms <- drop.terms(fterms, dropx = idx, keep.response = TRUE)
  return(formula(new_fterms))
}
```

Apply the function:

```
formula1 <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2

# the term that should be removed
to_remove <- "x1"

remove_terms(formula1, to_remove)
# y ~ x2 + x3
```

Comment: This works perfectly... unless the formula contains `lmer` grouping terms, e.g. `(1|group)`, then is removes the `()` parenthesis...